# Special characters not showing in pandoc html output

Tags: html, utf-8, pandoc

I am trying to get special characters (for foreign surnames) working in pandoc. I followed the instructions [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) and made sure all special characters are represented using UTF encoding (as per [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm). I chose HTML Entity (decimal) option. The resulting files work well when converting to docx or pdf but not html. Is there an encoding that will work for all three output types, or do I need to include some other option?

Here is a line of markdown code for conversion using the special character encoding

```markdown
some example text with special characters &#197;, &#228;, &#246;
```

which should print as

> some example text with special characters Å, ä, ö

pandoc commands

```
pandoc example.md -o example.docx  # Works

pandoc example.md -o example.pdf   # Works

pandoc example.md -o example.html  # Doesn't work
```

running via inconv does not change output behaviour

```
iconv -t utf-8 example.md | pandoc -o example.html  # Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 47):

Try

```
pandoc example.md -s -o example.html
```

instead. The additional `-s` (for "stand-alone") makes pandoc insert the necessary metadata to create a full HTML file instead of just the HTML snippet that directly corresponds to the text in example.md. As part of the metadata, pandoc also generates the information that the file is UTF8 encoded. Your browser needs this piece of information to display the special characters correctly.

If you cannot use the `-s` flag for some reason, make sure to tell the browser about the UTF8 some other way.

Comment: Not working if there are UTF-8 Chinese characters. Had to resort to browser text encoding.

Comment: not useful if your using the summary.md and not standalone

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the option  `--ascii` to produce pure-ascii-output with special charactes encoded as entities.

Comment: This worked for me when using powershell to copy markdown into a format I could paste into microsoft Teams: `Get-Clipboard | pandoc --ascii | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to _layouts/default.html in the  tag when using the summary.md and you are not able to use the -s for standalone.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html
change    data-charset="iso-8859-15" to data-charset="utf-8"
example:

```
    <section
data-markdown="slides/demo.md"
          data-separator="\n---\n"
          data-separator-vertical="^\n\n"
          data-separator-notes="\n> >"
          data-charset="utf-8">
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share how this code was generated? It doesn't look as if it was produced by pandoc.